# Reverse an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a function to reverse an array and I think there are some issues with the same. Please guide me in the right path to get this sorted out.

Function:

```
void reversearr (int arr[], int arrlen)

    {
        int a, b, arrtemp[arrlen];
        b=arrlen;
        for (a=0; a<=arrlen; a++)
        {
            arr[a] = arrtemp[b];
            b--;
        }
        printf("\nthe reversed array is");

        for(b=0; b<arrlen; b++)
        {
            printf("%d",arrtemp[b]);
        }
    }
```

the function is called in this way

```
reversearr(arr,max);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void reversearr (int arr[], int arrlen)
{  
    int a, tmp;
    for (a = 0; a < arrlen / 2; ++a)
    {
         tmp = arr[a];
         arr[a] = arr[arrlen - a - 1];
         arr[arrlen - a - 1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're copying from `arrtemp` which is uninitialised.

I think you'd want something like

```
void reversearr (int arr[], int arrlen)
{
    int a;
    for (a=0; a<arrlen/2; a++)
    {
        int tmp = arr[arrlen-1-a]
        arr[arrlen-1-a] = arr[a]
        arr[a] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two problems in

```
    int a, b, arrtemp[arrlen];
    b=arrlen;
    for (a=0; a<=arrlen; a++)
    {
        arr[a] = arrtemp[b];
        b--;
    }
```

1. `arrtemp[arrlen]` is out of bounds, the valid indices are 0 to `arrlen - 1`,
2. You are copying from the uninitialised `arrtemp` into the original `arr`.

Answer (score 1):

Valid indexes are 0 to `arrlen - 1` , so this:

```
for(a = 0; i <= arrlen; a++)
```

has an off-by-one error. You need `<`.

Also note that using an array with dynamic length like that is a pretty "new" thing in C, it should be fine but requires a C99 compiler. There's no benefit to doing it that way as compared to the O(1) (in storage) method of just swapping elements through a single temporary.

Comment: Actually, to reverse an array, one should loop until `i < arrlen/2`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong array for storing the reverse. Try the following code:

```
void reversearr (int arr[], int arrlen)

    {
        int a, b, arrtemp[arrlen];
        b=arrlen;
        for (a=0; a<=arrlen; a++)
        {
            arrtem[a] = arr[b];
            b--;
        }
        printf("\nthe reversed array is");

        for(b=0; b<arrlen; b++)
        {
            printf("%d",arrtemp[b]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, if there is an array and you have to reverse a string of every element:

```
var arr = ['woow is great budd','mu me lelo','wikindi'];

function reverseString(str){
    return (str === '') ? '' : reverseString(str.substr(1)) + str.charAt(0);
}

for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   console.log(reverseString(arr[i]));
}
```